# Can I use ctrl+ tab as a short key in my aspx file

Tags: jquery

In my aspx file, I use jQuery tabs and I need to change these tabs by pressing <kbd>ctrl + tab</kbd>, but as you know this combined key has been used for changing browser tabs and I need to make that disable and instead of that change these jQuery tabs.

Comment: I'd hate you for the rest of my life if you took ctrl - tab away from me in your website. :)

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default action using:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this should stop any default behavior

    // switch tab function
});
```

As you can see here in SO, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> makes the text bold (on Firefox it should open bookmark window, but they `override` this behavior).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doing its default action, in Firefox at least.  When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed (in contrast to the vast majority of other key combinations), no event is fired on the window, so you can neither prevent it nor respond to it.

Comment: I can confirm that Firefox will take over Ctrl+Tab and would not respond to preventDefault or return false.